# How to follow instructions made for linux on windows? Flashing firmware

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, flash, firmware

I'm trying to flash a firmware on to a stm32f3discovery board. https://github.com/yetifrisstlama/Foculus_Rift_Tracker_STM32F3DISCOVERY
These are the instructions I am trying to follow but they are for ubuntu and I am using windows 8.1. If anyone knows how to flash using a different method or how to just tweak this to work on windows all help is appreciated.

Comment: You either use something like cygwin, and run the software or depending on the hardware you have to flash, you attach it to a linux virtual machine.  The simplest solution of course is to get yourself a linux machine and don't try to cram a square peg into a hole that only accepts round pegs.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best ways to solve "this isn't meant for Windows"-issues is to look for a solution that's actually built for Windows, or to install a Linux partition so you can follow things faithfully.

Anyways, to answer your question specifically, especially if you attempt this kind of thing often, I'd recommend right now that you consider getting Cygwin for your system to minimize the differences between the steps you're actually performing and the steps in whatever tutorial you're following. That should increase the likelihood of success, at least assuming you're not looking to build something that runs with a GUI.

If you're lucky, you'll find all of the packages you need to use to follow the steps in Cygwin's package-manager, and will not have to build required packages (or their dependancies) from source for them to work.

There are no solid guarantees even when installing things on Linux according to prescribed directions that all will go smoothely, so keep in mind that the more complicated a task you're trying to complete in a different environment, the more things that can go wrong.

Comment: Well then maybe you could answer this question. When I did create a linux partition. Linux could not connect to ethernet and without a wifi chip it basically rendered linux unusable. any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: @user1991588 Not all Linux-distributions are created equal for the hardware you run them on; some are fine where others won't have drivers all drivers out of the box. Especially in the situation where Linux does not natively recognize your network-adapters, it's best to have another computer on standby so you can fetch the right drivers, and move them over via a flash drive (assuming your USBs work). It's also nice to have another computer to google any problems you're encountering early. Look for posts from other people who want drivers for the same components as you have and work from there.

Comment: I was using the newest ubuntu which relies on internet to even install so I shouldnt of had any problems however I did and doing research could not figure it out.

Comment: @user1991588 Then don't use an online-install-only version of Ubuntu. Instead, configure a liveCD or liveUSB of Ubuntu. Live-boot media generally give you the option of installing for real and then rebooting to that install on your HDD. That will give you a way of getting a working install of Ubuntu so you can stick the right drivers on for network-components and then be off and running.